# Foundation 5: reveal modal not firing "opened" callback

Tags: zurb-foundation

```
// this should fire an alert when the reveal modal is opened by clicking "click me for a modal"
// this similar setup was working in foundation 4

$(function(){
  $(document).foundation();
  $("#myModal").foundation({
    reveal: {
      opened: function () {
        alert("open debug this should fire");
        console.log("this should log");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

### Reduced test-case: http://codepen.io/austinpray/pen/FoqLr

The modal opens just fine but none of the callbacks or parameters are honored. If I was to set `animation: "none"` it would not honor that either. Is there something I am missing here about the new syntax? The [docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html) haven't been updated fully yet, so this I am a bit in the dark.

### Relevant Documentation

[Reveal](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html)

[The new javascript syntax](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html)

> Configure on the fly
>   New to Foundation 5, you can now reconfigure instances of your plugin after the page has loaded and Foundation has already been initialized.

[Upgrading to the new syntax](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/upgrading.html)

Comment: I've had the same issue, seems the documentation between Reveal and Orbit show totally different syntax. I've tried different things found in the [plugin](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/js/foundation/foundation.reveal.js) but none worked. I've filed an [issue](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/3809) with them so we'll see.

Answer (score 3):

In order to bind to a particular event, you need to do so explicitly after the plugin has been initialized. Here is your example code corrected:

```
$(function(){
  $(document).foundation();
  $("#myModal").on("opened", function(){
    alert("open debug this should fire");
    console.log("this should log");
  });
});
```

I tested this on the codepen link you posted and it worked.

From my understanding, only the plugin options can be configured on initalization.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to update this ticket for Foundation 5.5.2. The below code fires correctly.

```
$(document).foundation();
$("#myModal").on("opened.fndtn.reveal", function(){
  console.log("this should log");
});
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with a Foundation v5.5.3 site I need to extend. The test case shows the modal reveal div at the bottom of the html and not hidden like it should be.  Has the test-case code rotted in the past 4 1/2 years and what is required to fix it?

Comment: make sure the attributes are set correctly on the div

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).foundation();
  $("#myModal").on("opened", function(){
    console.log("this should log BUT ONLY ONCE");
  });
```

This code doesn't work for nested popups. In newest version, this way of calling it is **fully deprecated**.

To be sure, that `opened` event will be triggered no matter if popup is nested or not, type the code in the way mentioned [in documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html#event-bindings):

in my view:

```
<div id="#myModal", class="reveal-modal" data-reveal=""></div>
```

in js file:

```
$(document).foundation();
$(document).on("opened.reveal-modal", function(){
  console.log("this should log EVEN ON NESTED POPUP");
});
```

Comment: I noticed, that doing it this way, this `opened` event is tracked twice on nested popup.